# How to split column in table to multiple columns based on the values of the original column

Tags: powerbi

I'm all new to Power BI so please bare with me ..

I have imported an XML file with lots of data, and have from that generated a table where there are 2 columns that 1. contains multiple value types and values. I will show you in the screendump.

how do I split this column into multiple columns based on the values in the 1 column ?
I hope this makes sense ..

As you can see in the attached screendump the 2 columns contains lots of parameters with according values .. I want to split the 2 columns into multiple columns where each row will contain the values from the other column.

I hope this makes sense ortherwise just feel free to ask.

I tried to group, split the cells and merge them

Comment: Missing screen dump. Update the question with a few sample rows in [markdown format](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), together with the desired resulting format.